# Python - Foursquare API "Missing Auth Credentials'" userless search?

Tags: python, authentication, foursquare

I am trying to use the foursquare API for the first time and have not been able to get a 200 status code no matter what I tried. Using directly the code foursquare provides in its docs, I attempt to do a userless request, replacing my client ID and secret where necessary.

```
def places_search(term,street, zipcode):
    params = dict(
        client_id='MY_CLIENT_ID',
        client_secret='MY_CLIENT_SECRET',
        v='20181122',
        near=street + 'New York, NY ' + zipcode,
        query=term,
        limit=1
    )
    url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore"
    resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
    #grabbing the JSON result
    data = json.loads(resp.text)

    return data

print(places_search("starbucks","3rd avenue","10009"))
```

I get the following error code:

```
{'meta': {'code': 400, 'errorType': 'invalid_auth', 'errorDetail': 'Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication for details.', 'requestId': '5bf6cbb26a607137bc33b7f2'}, 'response': {}}
```

I find it odd given my request is userless and matches exactly the way they outline it in the docs... Would you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: even using the below that comes right from foursquare and plugging in today's date as well as the client_id and client_secret, i get the same error
`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=YYYYMMDD`

Comment: I implemented your code and it works fine for me. Maybe your client_id/client_secret is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication):

> To make a userless request, specify your consumer key’s Client ID and
>   Secret instead of an auth token in the request URL.

Like this:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=YYYYMMDD
```

Since you are passing the credentials as the request parameters, the server cannot authenticate you.

Comment: I am still getting the same error with 

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=2nd+avenue+12th+streetNew+York%2C+NY+10009&client_id=clientid&client_secret=clientsecret&v=20181122`